# ApplicationInfo for Settings pages in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-applicationinfo

I'm trying to get the **ApplicationInfo** for **Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS** or **Settings.ACTION_BATTERY_SAVER_SETTINGS**, so that I can launch them directly.

I tried following steps but it's return **setting's ApplicationInfo**.

```
private static final String[] SETTINGS_ACTION_MENUS = new String[]{
      Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS,Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT};


public void getSettingPages(){
    for(String menu : SETTINGS_ACTION_MENUS){
        final Intent intent = new Intent(menu);
        ComponentName componentName = intent.resolveActivity(packageManager);
        if(componentName != null){
            try {
                ApplicationInfo info = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(componentName.getPackageName(),0);
                if(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName) != null){
                    launchableApps.add(info);
                }
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried following steps but it's return setting's ApplicationInfo

That is because those `Intent` actions are tied to activities in the Settings app. Individual activities do not have their own `ApplicationInfo`.